# Multiple conditions in QT pro file

Tags: qt, qmake

How do you check multiple conditions in QT pro file?
For example, how to add multiple conditions to the below snippet.

```
DEFINES += QT_FORCE_ASSERTS

win32 {
    CURR_PLATFORM = $$(CURR_PLATFORM) # read from environment
    CURR_ARCH = $$(CURR_ARCH) # read from environment
    !(equals(CURR_PLATFORM, "win32") && equals(CURR_ARCH, "x64")){
        error(CURR_PLATFORM must be set to \"win32\" currently set to: \"$$(CURR_PLATFORM)\")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `:` for "and", `|` for "or". However, you can't put them inside parentheses. So this won't work:

```
!(equals(CURR_PLATFORM, "win32") : equals(CURR_ARCH, "x64")) { ... }
```

You have to change it to get rid of the parentheses:

```
!equals(CURR_PLATFORM, "win32") | !equals(CURR_ARCH, "x64") { ... }
```

Comment: Since Qt 5 there is the test function `if(condition)` which can be used to group boolean expressions as if they had been put inside parentheses. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#if-condition.